# Font conversion between Apple and Windows and vice versa

Tags: windows, mac, fonts

What are the font types are used on Apple system and how to convert font types from Mac to Windows and Windows to Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Windows has Mac font equivalents, check them out [here](http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/WindowsMacFonts.html).

Comment: that's a listing of font substitutes, which although useful to some, doesn't in fact answer the question of what font file formats are used on Mac and Windows and how one would convert between them.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's Windows uses [OpenType fonts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenType). It also supports the older Truetype font system. Earlier versions of Windows could support Postscript Type 1 fonts by use of third-party products (e.g. from Adobe).

Apple's OS-X uses [AAT fonts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Advanced_Typography). Recent versions of OS-X also have limited support for OpenType fonts.

For best results it is better to repurchase a font in the native format of the platform than to attempt to convert them. Each font system has features that the others lack and which are not amenable to automatic translation. Programs such as Fontforge can [convert the common features of fonts](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/faq.html#OT2AAT)